# PHP: 'method doesnt exist', but it does

Tags: php, oop

I have this strange error,

When I call `$element_attrs = $element -> attributes();` I get a notice saying the attribute method does not exist:

```
Call to undefined method stdClass::attributes();
```

now when I call `die( get_class( $element ) );` Right before the `attributes()` call, php returns `Select_Element` which is correct!

`Form_Element` contains the `attribute();` method.

I am positive `Select_Element` extends `Form_Element` and both files are included indefinately.

**HOWEVER**

if I call:

```
if ( method_exists($element, "attributes") ) {
    $element_attrs = $element -> attributes();
}
```

IT WORKS! method_exists returns true, and `attributes()` is called! but when I remove the `if` command, I get the error notice again...

What the hell is going on!

**CODE**

```
interface Element{
    public function __construct( $element );
    public function parse();
}

class Form_Element implements Element{

    protected $element;

    public function __construct($json_element){
        $this -> element = $json_element;
    }

    public function parse(){
        // Removed parsing code, unrelated
    }

    ... removed unrelated methods ...

    public function attributes( $key = null, $value = null ){
        if ( is_null( $key ) ){
            return $this -> element -> attributes;
        }
        else{
            $this -> element -> attributes -> $key = $value;
        }
    }
}

class Select_Element extends Form_Element implements Element{

    public function __construct( $element ) {
        parent::__construct( $element );
    }

    public function parse(){
        // Removed parsing code, unrelated
    }
}
```

**and this is where the code is called in a `Form` class :**

// note: `$this -> elements` is an array of `Form_Element` objects

```
public function edit_form($name_of_element, $name_of_value, $value){
    foreach ( $this -> elements as $element ){
        if ( method_exists($element, "attributes") ) {
            $element_attrs = $element -> attributes();
        }
        if ( $element_attrs -> name == $name_of_element ){
            switch ( $name_of_value ){
                case "selected" :
                    $element -> selected( $value );
                    break;
                case "options" :
                    $element -> options( $value );
                    break;
                case "value" :
                    $element -> value( $value );
                    break;
                // add more support as needed
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Does anybody know why PHP thinks `attributes();` doesnt exist? Even though `method_exists($element, "attributes");` returns `true` ?

Comment: The object you are calling the method on is a `stdClass` (that's what you usually get when deserializing json or casting an array to object), so it's clearly not an instance of your `Form_Element` class.

Comment: @ThiefMaster but he says `get_class( $element )` return the correct type.

Comment: are you sure your `element` is an instance of `Form_Element`?

Comment: is there any space b/w the operator ? It should be like this  `$element->attributes();`

Comment: @Truth I think the simple answer here is that he's in a loop, and `die()` does not necessary stop the loop with the element that is causing the problem. I'm willing to bet there is no PHP bug involved.

Comment: @sakhunzai It doesn't matter.

Comment: Having spaces around `->` is ugly though

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You say you are in a loop with this.

Most likely, the code you show is called twice, once with `$element` being the desired object, and once not - when you use `method_exists()`, the code walks past that point, and if you don't use it, it crashes.

When you use `die()`, the loop terminates *at the first element.* But that is not necessarily the element that is causing the problem.

The error message

```
Call to undefined method stdClass::attributes();
```

supports this: note the `stdClass` where it should read `Form_Element`.

So you need to find out why `$element` is not always the object you want it to be.

Comment: You were correct, I can't believe I didn't realise I was going through a loop -.-

Answer (score 1):

Probably you write `die()` after first step of your loop, but got error in other steps.

Change `die( get_class( $element ) );` to `print( get_class( $element ).'<br/>' );` and you'll see in which line you got error, and probably in that line attribute will be empty.